# Syncing Google Earth My Places data in OS X?

Tags: google-earth, osx

Since Google hasn't implemented a sync service for Google Earth's *My Places* data, I'm trying to make this work manually between my home and work computers, one OS X the other Windows.  Windows side works fine - I've just redesignated the KML path in registry (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Google Earth Plus\KMLPath`) to a Dropbox.  The problem's on the Mac side.  I've tried replacing the myplaces.kml with a symlink, but this failed as the new object is somehow automatically overwritten by a backup (even when the backup in the same folder (`/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google Earth/`) has been manually deleted).  So I'm trying by adding a 'Network Link' folder to My Places, linking to the dropbox kml.  This half works - edits from Windows side load up in Mac side, but edits/additions in Mac side placed in the networked folder are not saved upon exit.

Does anyone know the reason for this failure to sync, or of an alternative method that works on OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing the same frustration in syncing Google Earth placemarks between Windows and OS X. The reason that syncing fails for Mac OS X is that Google Earth for that platform issues a file system delete of myplaces.kml  and creates a new file into which it flushes its memory contents.

I have created a hard link (not symbolic) in the Google Earth directory point to my Dropbox copy of myplaces.kml

```
ln ~/Dropbox/myplaces.kml ~/Library/Application Support/Google Earth/
```

I verified that the hard link and dropbox file are the same inode, meaning the same file.

Upon opening Google Earth and manipulating what it had to read from the hard link, it deletes the hard link and creates a new inode of the same name.

```
ls -il myplaces.kml
```

Comment: Returning to this problem.  New strategy to use unison app to sync actual files with others in dropbox.

Comment: Seems to work. Install unison with homebrew then add following to crontab:
`/usr/local/bin/unison '/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google Earth' {path to dropbox/etc} -batch -debug update+ > /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

I just make a symbolic link to the whole directory.

```
ln -s /Users/adam/Dropbox/Google\ Earth/ /Users/adam/Library/Application\ Support/
```